# Not able to update status when I'm loading Facebook fragment over Activity?

Tags: android, facebook

I can Login to facebook by loading a loginButton of Facebook from fragment over Activity.

Now I wish to update status -

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

Request uploadRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
            Session.getActiveSession(), img, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Photo uploaded successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    Bundle params = uploadRequest.getParameters();
    params.putString("name", message);
    uploadRequest.setParameters(params);

    uploadRequest.executeAsync();
```

The status is not updated. When I debug the app I see below code @ uploadRequest object.

```
{Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[public_profile, basic_info, email, contact_email, publish_actions, user_photos, user_friends]}, appId:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}, graphPath: me/photos, graphObject: null, httpMethod: POST, parameters: Bundle[{picture=android.graphics.Bitmap@b4d6b658}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on your Activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Comment: I'm simply loading fragment over activity. I'm not overriding anything on Activity. I have Implemented everything in Fragment.

Comment: you need to retain the session, this is the way

Comment: I'm using UiLifecycleHelper class and it does session management on its own. The Thing is I've implemented it in Fragment instead of FragmentActivity. If I don't override onActivityResult() in Activity then the call is directly transfered to onActivityResult() of Fragment.

Comment: Thnx for helping me out. But my scenario is different and ur suggestions are for Activity.